# Stationary waves as eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator in the ground state of the hydrogen atom

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, schroedinger-equation, eigenvalue, hydrogen

Taking the Hamiltonian operator $H = T + V$, I know that the eigenfunctions are stationary waves, this means that the wave function $\Psi$ is eigenfunction of T + V, this is also true in the case of the ground state of the hydrogen atom, but why is an eigenfunction of T + V? $\Psi$ can be eigenfunction only of the potential energy operator or the KE operator in this case? I mean, what properties have the sum of T + V that leads to an stationary wave as a eigenfunction in this particular case? I try to see what´s the problem on this and I don't find any reason that tells me that the stationary wave can not be an eigenfunction of T or V operators only. Can you help me to understand this?

Comment: So you are essentially asking where the [time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation) comes from, and why is it the Hamiltonian $H$ appearing there?

Comment: The Hamiltonian represents the total energy of the system, do you think that each energy separately are conserved? They are not as both the kinetic and potential energies change in time, and if each was to have their own stationary state eigenvalues, those eigenvalues would have to be constant in time.

Comment: Let me explain a bit more, taking the above we know that in the ground state of hydrogen atom we have a potential V, this potential is constant (or not?) then we can find a stationary wave function that is the eigenfunction of the V operator, then the problem I see is with the KE, I mean, the real question is: I can find the eigenfunction of the Hamiltonian knowing the eigenfunctions of T and V?

Comment: @DoubtDude If you are asking whether you can obtain the spectrum of $A+B$ from the spectra of $A$ and $B$ separately, the answer is generally no.

Comment: The potential $V\sim 1/r$ is certainly not constant…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero Constant usually means unchanging in time, so $\frac1r$ is constant. I think you mean to say that it's not uniform.

Comment: @DoubtDude What makes you think the eigenfunctions of $V$ are physically meaningful?

Comment: @Sandejo Clearly this doesn’t work: then the kinetic energy would have to be a constant as well.  There is nothing to suggest that $r$ does not change in time and thus that $V$ does not change in time.  Indeed that would be so for an elliptical orbit: $r=r(t)$.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero In the Schrödinger picture, $\hat r$ and $\hat p$ are constant, as are $T$ and $V$.

Comment: @Sandejo with due respect: $\hat r$ is not constant since it has a non-zero variance.  Same holds for $\hat p$.  but your mixing things:  that the operators are not time dependent does not imply the observables are constants.

Comment: @ZeroTheHero My point was purely about terminology; I was just saying that, in my experience, "constant" usually means not time dependent.

Comment: @Sandejo pray then suggest an observable that is NOT constant?

Comment: @ZeroTheHero A non-constant operator could be one associated with a time-dependent perturbation.

Comment: @Sandejo this would be a unique definition.  The normal definition is that this operator commutes with the Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 0):

The stationary states of the system are defined as the eigenfunctions of the Hamiltonian operator.
$$H|\psi\rangle =E|\psi\rangle $$
These eigenfunctions are necessary to be an eigenfunction of kinetic or potential. This is because these are functions of $x$ and $p$ which don't commute with each other.
$$[H,K(p)]\not=0\not=[H,V(x)]$$

Only for free particle when $V(x)=0$ we have
$$H=\frac{p^2}{2m}\rightarrow [H,p]=0$$
therefore kinetic energy (or momentum) and Hamiltonian have the same eigenfunctions.